# Is there a command like namei for OS X?

Tags: permission, homebrew

I'm sifting through some incorrect permission issues and discovered the [namei](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/namei.1.html) command for Linux. Homebrew doesn't currently have a Mac port.

> namei - follow a pathname until a terminal point is found

Is there a command or series of commands that can be used to accomplish the same thing on OS X?

Answer (score 7):

Macports has a port of it: https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/devel/util-linux/Portfile

I did try to make a homebrew recipe for it, but there were some issues getting it to compile. It's definitely possible, but there are some problems to work out.

*Update*:

I've made a formula that can be installed with:

```
brew install mkdryden/homebrew-misc/namei
```

This is the original version, not the version pulled into util-linux. (not sure how much has changed since the original)

Comment: Not a homebrew expert, but does that use the file at https://github.com/mkdryden/homebrew-misc/blob/master/Formula/namei.rb?

Comment: @mwfearnley Yes, that's the recipe file. You can look at it to see the patch I had to make to get it to compile, though that was 5 years ago; I'm not sure if it still works properly.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me yesterday :)

Comment: Interestingly, today, I found `namei` in the Homebrew `util-linux` package but not in that for MacPorts.

Answer (score 7):

You can download the source code for `namei` from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/namei/files/latest/download). To compile, you need to delete the `#include <sys/sysmacros.h>` line from `stat.c`, then run `make`.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that the version in util-linux was based on the one from SourceForge. I did eventually figure out how to get the util-linux one to compile, but it comes with many other utilities, a lot of which are redundant on OS X. Anyways, see my updated answer for the homebrew formula of the original. Beware, installing from source with `make install` can cause issues if `/usr/local/bin' is ahead of `/usr/bin` in your PATH as it installs hardlinked to `stat`. The formula avoids this and only installs under namei.